# Two or more table with serial with uniq nums in every table

Tags: sql, postgresql, auto-increment

I've 2 table with serial field (in table "m" it's field "uniq" and in table "u" it's field "uniq").
But, if I insert data in (for example) u. Autoincrement function make +1 for next row in u (from 1 to 2), but if after this action I insert data in another table (for example) m autoincrement field write down not next value in column (1,2,3..), but 3, even if in field was 1.

It means, what autoincrement function incremented every single value in database in series, but not in the table.

sorry for such a poor description of the problem and bad english = )

Comment: Do you have tables with increment row? is the problem inserting data in that tables?

Comment: Nope, it's not a problem inserting.. And yes, I've a tables w/increment row..
But I wanna have row's with **uniq** numbers in table, not in database.
For example: table "u": 1 a@a.a 2 b@b.b table "m": 1 asd 2 sad
But not table "u": 1 a@a.a 2 b@b.b table "m": 3 asd 4 sad

Comment: please post the `create table` statements for the tables and the inserts you use. Ideally as an http://sqlfiddle.com example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this if you want having an id which is `unique in all tables`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq;  

CREATE TABLE table1(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEXTVAL('id_seq'),Test1 varchar);
CREATE TABLE table2(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEXTVAL('id_seq'),Test2 varchar);
```

try something like this to create `unique id for each table`

```
CREATE TABLE table3(id serial,Test3 varchar);
CREATE TABLE table4(id serial,Test4 varchar);
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/113cd/1)

Comment: take a look at `Table3,Table4` in my answer,that will give your answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's what I need! (U're awesome U_Ov)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a unique ID over tables "a" and "b". So create one table with a serial column just for having your key (eg. "id_table") and all other tables have this key as foreign key. Every time you need a new ID, you insert in your "id_table" and point to this new key.

Comment: Nope, I need unique ID not over all tables. I need unique ID in table A and in table B. (they can have the same values)

Comment: OK then over tables A and B, no other tables are spoken of. Use this schema only for those tables, for which you need a unique Key across  - I edited my answer accodingly

Comment: Omg, I just need to successive values ​​in each of the tables, not even unique, they should just be serial